# Kettle, insert two column into one column

Tags: merge, kettle

I'm just starting kettle
I want to know how where I combine if I possessed two same column data (from excel) ex : the place of birth and home town into one column in table city
in order to more clearly :

column in excel

> 1. name
> 2. place of birth
> 3. current city ​

serve two tables

Table 1:

> 1. id
> 2. name
> 3. (id city) place of birth
> 4. (id city) current city

table 2:

> 1. id city
> 2. city

anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with Merge Join (using id city as key) http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Merge+Join

Comment: do you have some tutorial with example for this function pentaho kettle?